# AutoHotKey use mousewheel over the taskbar to scroll open windows

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

The desired behavior is to have mouse scroll through all open windows in a workspace, like issuing AltTab, or ShiftAltTab. I use a SetTimer, such that I can scroll through multiple windows not just 1, within a given time then after a delay of inactivity the selected window is maximised. Here is the script I tried to create

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2

#HotIf MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
{
WheelUp::
{
  Send "{ALT DOWN}{TAB}"
  SetTimer ReleaseAlt, 1000
}

WheelDown::
{
  Send "{ALT DOWN}{SHIFT}{TAB}"
  SetTimer ReleaseAlt, 1000
}


ReleaseAlt() 
{
  static idle := 1000
  if (A_TimeIdle >= idle)
    Send "{ALT UP}"
}

}

MouseIsOver(WinTitle) {
    MouseGetPos ,, &Win
    return WinExist(WinTitle " ahk_id " Win)
}
```

This only takes the first scroll up / down action, so I cannot scroll through multiple windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Wildcard(*)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard): Fires the hotkey even if extra modifiers (in this case
> Alt and/or Shift) are being held down.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

    
#HotIf MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd") || WinActive("Task Switching") 

    *WheelUp::
    {
        Send "{SHIFT UP}{ALT DOWN}{TAB}"
        SetTimer ReleaseKeys, 1000
    }

    *WheelDown::
    {
        Send "{ALT DOWN}{SHIFT DOWN}{TAB}"
        SetTimer ReleaseKeys, 1000
    }

#HotIf

ReleaseKeys() 
{
    static idle := 1000
    if (A_TimeIdle >= idle)
        Send "{ALT UP}{SHIFT Up}"
}

MouseIsOver(WinTitle) {
    MouseGetPos ,, &Win
    return WinExist(WinTitle " ahk_id " Win)
}
```

Comment: Added `{SHIFT UP}` to the WheelUp hotkey for the case you want to send AltTab after ShiftAltTab and the Task Switcher is still active.